# Tkinter layout changes from Spyder to Command Prompt

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, spyder

I have built a simple GUI in tkinter that goes through an algorithm to fit Radial Velocity data. Everything works fine in Spyder, however when I try to run the file in command prompt the GUI's dimensions change drastically. [This is how it is supposed to look and how it looks in Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H3o3.jpg). [This is how it looks when it's run in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAM5m.jpg). The plots that are produced show the same behavior described. I've tried setting all the windows in Tkinter so that they are unable to be resized. I'm not sure what else to try. Is there a way to fix this? I am on Windows 10 64bit, Python 3.5.4, and Spyder 3.2.5.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what to try. I tried setting the windows so that they're unable to be resized, but that doesn't fix the main resizing issue between Spyder and cmd.

Comment: Thank you for adding information about what you've tried. Tipp: try to insert the images directly into the post instead of linking to them.

Comment: It looks to me like Spyder simply configures some different default fonts. I recommend printing out the font that is being used in each case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. It's due to the fact that Spyder automatically overrides high DPI scaling, whereas both Python.exe and Pythonw.exe do not. The solution was to check the 'Override High DPI Scaling behavior' option under the compatibility tab for both python.exe and pythonw.exe.